# Display different content based on last visited page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm working on a website that hosts content for different cities. Each content belongs necessarily to a city.

The goal is to display articles to the user based on the city they visited the last.

Today I have a perfectly working solution but it reduces considerably the performance of the website as it works based on a redirect.

Here is the code I'm currently using in my index.php:

```
$request_path = request_path();
if (empty($request_path)) {
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  $is_https = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on';
  $http_protocol = $is_https ? 'https' : 'http';
  $base_root = $http_protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

  $base_url = $base_root;

  if ($dir = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\/')) {
    $base_path = $dir;
    $base_url .= $base_path;
  }

  if (isset($_COOKIE['city']) && !empty($_COOKIE['city'])) {
    if (in_array($_COOKIE['city'], $cities)) {
      $url = $base_url . '/' . $_COOKIE['city'];
      header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 301);
      exit;
    }
  }

  $url = $base_url . '/city1';
  setrawcookie('city', rawurlencode('city1'), REQUEST_TIME + 31536000, '/');
  header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 301);
  exit;
}
else {
  $request_path_array = explode('/', $request_path);
  $select_city = check_plain($request_path_array[0]);
  // get city from url at first,if not, get that from cookie.
  if (in_array($select_city, $cities)) {
    $city = $select_city;
    setrawcookie('city', rawurlencode($select_city), REQUEST_TIME + 31536000, '/');
  }
  else {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['city'])) {
      $city_from_cookie = $_COOKIE['city'];
      if (in_array($city_from_cookie, $cities)) {
        $city = $city_from_cookie;
      }
      else {
        $city = 'city1';
      }
    }
    else {
      $city = 'city1';
    }

  }
}
```

every request to the website goes through this script and sets a global variable that is used on the different db queries to get the appropriate content.

I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this. I'm open to any solution as I'm working on rebuilding the whole platform and this is a key feature.

Please keep in mind that speed and stability are the main KPIs.

Thanks,

Comment: If your "city" pages are totally independent from each other, redirect is not the worst option I think. In this case subdomains could also be an interesting alternative. But if you just need to display some city-dependent articles on a page, I would always load the same page but fetch specific articles from db or whatever. I think you could simplify your cookie code shown above. Maybe storing the whole path in the cookie could also be a way to reduce your redirect code.

Comment: @user1915746 The page layout is exactly the same, the content however is different. The issue I'm finding with the redirect is that it takes ~100ms. I thought I could save some of it

Comment: Then redirect does not make sense to me. Can't you just load content based on users city-cookie? Maybe an additional field  "city" in your content table for which you can filter when fetching from db.